# Photoshop редактирование SmartObject

Tags: javascript, photoshop, jsx

Есть графический файл mockup psd.
Внутри файла смартобъекты.
Как получить доступ к этому смартобъекту и редактировать? (поменять слой, удалить слой).
Пытаюсь обратиться в mockup как к обычному слою, но так не работает.

```
  var mockup    = open(File('mockup.psd'));
  app.activeDocument = mockup

  var layerRef = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("Layer_name");
  layerRef.remove(); //например просто удалить
```

[image: обращаюсь к смартобъекту как к слою]

[image: Так нельзя]

Как правильно редактировать смарт-объект?

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос.

```
runMenuItem(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'))
```